# Can anyone tell me what the IC is?

Tags: led, integrated-circuit

I am working on the re-design of an old board, but due to many reasons, the original design document is incomplete. So I sometimes have to figure out what an IC is. Here is one I couldn't figure out, and I would appreciate if anyone could give me some hint. The IC seems to be related to LED diode.

[image]

Comment: this would be much easier with context. I.e., show us as much of the circuit around this

Comment: What is it connected to? Any of the pins obviously power, ground or not connected? What power voltage? Which pins are connected the LED? What are the others connected to? What is the general purpose of that bit of the circuit? It would also help to include a schematic (as best you have) of that bit of the circuit, and a photo of that part of the PCB.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "unclear what you are asking" because no contextual information is provided.  If you are actually working on a *re-design* you have a general awareness of what most of it does, and you can provide the context of this part even if you are uncertain what *it* does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late update. I now know what the IC is. It is constant current LED driver IC. Thanks to all who have commented.